# How to Synchronize Bokeh Wdigets Without Triggering Multiple Callbacks

Tags: python, callback, widget, bokeh

I have four graphs on separate tabs. There is a set of sliders on each tab, and each set of sliders is synchronized. For example, if a start slider on one tab is changed, then all of the start sliders (for all tabs) is set using this callback function:

```
def update_start(self, attr, old, new):
    print("Update Start")
    self.graph_start_time = new
    for ctrl in self.control_set:
        ctrl.start_slider.value = new
    self.update_source()
```

For a set of four start sliders, I see that the print statement is executed FIVE times.

I would like to disable each callback initially in the for-loop and then re-enable it on completion of each iteration of the for-loop, but I don't know how.

Another thing I don't understand is why this doesn't run as an infinite recursive loop. I'm assuming that the first print is from the initial callback, and the next four are from the for-loop queuing the callback on each iteration. If that were the case, then each queue of the callback should encounter the for-loop again, ad infinitum. But it only executes FIVE times before returning to normal operation of my program. Can someone explain what is going on here?

Comment: If you are setting all the sliders values to the same thing, why not use just one slider outside of the tabs widget that controls everything in the tabs?
Updating the slider value with the same value does not cause the callback to trigger again.

Comment: Good suggestion. I'm still learning and stumbled onto tabs. I will try that! Your second comment answers the question of why it doesn't recursively execute indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this interim solution. Not quite what I had in mind, but it works as I would expect it:

```
def update_start(self, attr, old, new):
    if self.lockout_control_update_callback == False:
        self.lockout_control_update_callback = True
        print("Update Start")
        self.graph_start_time = new
        for ctrl in self.control_set:
            ctrl.start_slider.value = new
        self.lockout_control_update_callback = False
        self.update_source()
```

I'm still looking for a better answer to disable the callback in the for-loop and a reason why the original doesn't recurse indefinitely.